# Buttons from different classes

Tags: jquery, html

In the below code i want to remove the corresponding rem button when i press the corresponding add button E.G. if i press add 1, rem 1 should be deleted... All this should be done using JQuery.. Someone pls help me...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input class="add" id="1" type="button" value="1"><br>
<input class="add" id="2" type="button" value="2"><br>
<input class="add" id="3" type="button" value="3"><br>
<input class="add" id="4" type="button" value="4"><br><br>

<input class="rem" id="r1" type="button" value="R1"><br>
<input class="rem" id="r2" type="button" value="R2"><br>
<input class="rem" id="r3" type="button" value="R3"><br>
<input class="rem" id="r4" type="button" value="R4"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't start an `id` attribute with a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('#r' + this.value).remove();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UE4w6/

Note, that I used `this.value` rather than `this.id` because ids starting with number can be unreliable in old  browsers.

By the way, plain javascript can also be very fun:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('add') && e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
        var rem = document.getElementById('r' + e.target.value);
        rem && rem.parentNode.removeChild(rem);
    }
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UE4w6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('#r' + $(this).val()).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it is working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.add').on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#r'+id).remove();            
        });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="add" id="1" type="button" value="1"><br>
<input class="add" id="2" type="button" value="2"><br>
<input class="add" id="3" type="button" value="3"><br>
<input class="add" id="4" type="button" value="4"><br><br>

<input class="rem" id="r1" type="button" value="R1"><br>
<input class="rem" id="r2" type="button" value="R2"><br>
<input class="rem" id="r3" type="button" value="R3"><br>
<input class="rem" id="r4" type="button" value="R4"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    $('.rem[id$="'+this.value+'"]').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

HTML:-

```
 <input class="add" id="1" data-id="r1" type="button" value="1"><br>
 <input class="add" id="2" data-id="r2" type="button" value="2"><br>
 <input class="add" id="3" data-id="r3" type="button" value="3"><br>
 <input class="add" id="4" data-id="r4" type="button" value="4"><br><br>

 <input class="rem" id="r1" type="button" value="R1"><br>
 <input class="rem" id="r2" type="button" value="R2"><br>
 <input class="rem" id="r3" type="button" value="R3"><br>
 <input class="rem" id="r4" type="button" value="R4"><br>
```

jQuery:-

```
$(function(){
  $('.add').click(function(){
      $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id')).toggle(); // or use hide();
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ugCy/